# Average Word Length .txt

Tags: java

I am having trouble finding the avg word length of a text file. The output I am getting is 0 for some reason. This program also finds the total number of words in a text file, which I have down, just having trouble with finding the average word length.

```
public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        String fileName= input.nextLine();
        FileReader wordReader;
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        try {
            wordReader=new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(wordReader);
            String wordCounter;
            int numberWords=0;
            double avgWord=0;
            double chara=0;


            while((wordCounter=reader.readLine()) !=null) {
                String []words=wordCounter.split(" ");

                for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
                {
                    numberWords++;
                }
            }
                while((wordCounter=reader.readLine()) !=null) {
                String []charWords=wordCounter.split("");
                for (int j=0;j<charWords.length;j++) {
                    chara++;
                }
                avgWord=chara/numberWords;


            }






            System.out.println("Total words: "+ numberWords);
            System.out.println("Average word length: "+ avgWord);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.out.println("Example of a valid input: /Users/Marcus/Documents/text.txt");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: please fix your indentation; it's really confusing for both us and you. In Eclipse you can do Ctrl-Shift-F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second while-loop will return immediately since `reader` has already been depleted.

```
while((wordCounter=reader.readLine()) !=null) {
```

You must first create a new `reader`.